# Simple Form gem: placeholders not showing with Internet Explorer V6-9 - Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, simple-form

I'm using the Simple Form Gem with Rails and have realised the placeholders don't show using Internet Explorer Versions 6-9. This really affects how I want the layout of my site. I can't find any recent information about this and especially nothing related to simple form. Is there any way round it? On part of my homepage it should look like the image below, however on IE it just displays as empty white form boxes, not good. I really don't want to have to put labels above for each box. Any help would be great thanks!  [image]

```
<%= simple_form_for @client, url: client_path, namespace: 'qq1' do |f| %>
                <%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", id: "first_name", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :last_name, placeholder: "Surname", id: "surname", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Email", id: "email", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number", id: "phone", label: false %>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <%= f.submit "Next", 'data-disable-with' => "Loading...", class: "btn btn-outline btn-xl", id: "send" %>
                </div>
<% end %>
```

HTML:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_client" id="qq1_new_client" action="/client" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="6J7tSBjzaHvJs/5aNG1tMDTjhUO5LReFXENA6ZMOrsZEQWGwblvXl6YWP7YGc5dTuD7gsUjhTlJMFqTApqBxTw==" />
                <div class="form-group string optional client_first_name"><input class="form-control string optional" placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="client[first_name]" id="qq1_client_first_name" /></div>
                <div class="form-group string optional client_last_name"><input class="form-control string optional" placeholder="Surname" type="text" name="client[last_name]" id="qq1_client_last_name" /></div>
                <div class="form-group email optional client_email"><input class="form-control string email optional" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="client[email]" id="qq1_client_email" /></div>
                <div class="form-group tel optional client_phone"><input class="form-control string tel optional" placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" name="client[phone]" id="qq1_client_phone" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right no-right-pad">
                    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Next" data-disable-with="Loading..." class="btn btn-outline btn-xl" id="send" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="success">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Internet Explorer version?

Comment: All as far as I'm aware

Comment: Placeholders are supported by Internet Explorer...this works on IE 11 https://jsfiddle.net/v73qrsqp/ ...can you paste the html of that form?

Comment: Sorry had difficulty figuring this out with IE, finally got a good emulator working. It seems this only relates to IE 6-9. Is there any workaround? I will add form code now thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the IE versions causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but that is rails code....I need the rendered html

Comment: Added rendered HTML. Thanks